# Translate website using Pretty URL's in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to learn how to develop my website using Laravel 5.

Now i'm working on the languages of the site, but I have some questions that I hope you guys might know how to solve.

I know that the Location service helps a lot when translating the site, but I want something a little more complicated. I want to put a `<select></select>` tag at the top of my header where the user will have the option to change to another language.

Right now, I have already created the following folders that will have all the information to be translated.

```
-resources
    -lang
        -en
            messages.php
        -es
            messages.php
```

Each **messages.php** file has the complete directory of the information to be translated.

I know how to do this using pure **php ($_SESSION)** and **jQuery**, but I have no idea how to do this with laravel.

I would like that the website has will look like this:

```
/[about] 
/[contact] 
/en 
/en/[about] 
/en/[contact] 
/fr 
/fr/[about]
/fr/[contact]
```

Hope you guys help.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

I just found a laravel package which can help to manage this kind specific issue in the proper way.

The package name is Laravel Localization and it's pretty easy to use.

[Link here](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)

Comment: What language are you going to load on /[ about ] and /[ contact ] ? Maybe the best will be to redirect to /en and load English by default?

Answer (score 0):

Use the directions from here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/localization

```
Route::get('{locale}/{page?}', function ($locale, $page == '') {
    App::setLocale($locale);    
    // your code
});
```

And as for the change of the language from a drop down, just redirect the users based on their choice with java script.